# Get differences between two list

Tags: c#, .net, object

I have a 2 lists of an object type:

```
List<MyClass> list1;

List<MyClass> list2;
```

What is the best way (performance and clean code) to extract differences in data between these two List?
I mean get objects that is added, deleted, or changed (and the change)?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397894.aspx

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "changed"? For example, if list1 has "foO" and list2 has "bar", is that an addition and a deletion, or a change?

Comment: Please give expected input and output. Your question does not make it clear whether you care about the order in which objects occur, or whether you can have duplicate objects in the same list, or how you determine whether two objects represent the same one, even if they are "changed".

Comment: Everyone has their fingers on trigger right now waiting on the edit :D

Comment: Any object has a key and based on it we can find it' new or changed

Answer (score 13):

Try `Except` with `Union`, but you'll need to do it for both in order to find differences in both.

```
var exceptions = list1.Except(list2).Union(list2.Except(list1)).ToList();
```

**OR as a Linq alternative, there could be a much faster approach: HashSet.SymmetricExceptWith():**

```
var exceptions = new HashSet(list1);

exceptions.SymmetricExceptWith(list2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<string> differenceQuery = list1.Except(list2);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397894.aspx

Comment: That won't give you the items only in list 2 :)

Comment: @MitchWheat - why does it matter about the time I posted the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `FindAll` to get the result you want, even you don't have `IEquatable` or `IComparable` implemented in your `MyClass`. Here is one example:

```
List<MyClass> interetedList = list1.FindAll(delegate(MyClass item1) {
   MyClass found = list2.Find(delegate(MyClass item2) {
     return item2.propertyA == item1.propertyA ...;
   }
   return found != null;
});
```

In the same way, you can get your interested items from `list2` by comparing to `list1`.

This strategy may get your "changed" items as well.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get items that are either in list1 or in list2 but not in both would be:

```
var common = list1.Intersect(list2);
var exceptions = list1.Except(common).Concat(list2.Except(common));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for objects comparison and loop around it for `List<T>`

```
public static void GetPropertyChanges<T>(this T oldObj, T newObj)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi in type.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        object selfValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(oldObj, null);
        object toValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(newObj, null);
        if (selfValue != null && toValue != null)
        {
            if (selfValue.ToString() != toValue.ToString())
            {
             //do your code
            }
        }
    }
}
```