# Compare 2 Collections and get Modified items

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two ObservableCollection in my application, one which contain the items of type `StoreSettings`
named "oldSettings" anothe collection named "_stores".

```
 public ObservableCollection<StoreSettings> oldSettings;
 private ObservableCollection<StoreSettings> _stores;
```

Here is my StoreSettings class

```
 public class StoreSettings :INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _autoAOD;

        public bool AutoAOD
        {
            get { return _autoAOD; }
            set { _autoAOD = value;
        }

        private bool _autoGRN;

        public bool AutoGRN
        {
            get { return _autoGRN; }
            set { _autoGRN = value;
        }

        private bool _directPurchase;

        public bool DirectPurchase
        {
            get { return _directPurchase; }
            set { _directPurchase = value;
        }
        private decimal _gustoreID;

        public decimal GUStoreID
        {
            get { return _gustoreID; }
            set { _gustoreID = value;
        }
        private string _storeCode;

        public string Storecode
        {
            get { return _storeCode; }
            set { _storeCode = value;
        }
```

I am updating some of the item's properties through my application, how can i find the modified items 
through linq?

this is what i have tried, but it always gives count "0"

```
  List<StoreSettings> result = _vmStoreconfig.oldSettings.Except(_vmStoreconfig.Stores).ToList();
```

Comment: You know you can just do `public decimal GUStoreID { get; set; }`, right? No need to implement all the accessors manually. This isn't Java.

Comment: @rightfold i know that, It is a silverlight application, i had to do that since am using MVVM

Comment: Do both oldSettings and _stores contain the same *instances* of the StoreSettings objects? The `Except()` method, by default, doesn't know how to differentiate two different instances of the same Store unless they're the same instance, or unless an EqualityComparer is at play.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan yes same instance

Comment: Also, you can use auto-properties in Silverlight as well, as far as I know. MVVM requires that you use *properties* rather than *fields*, but they don't need explicit implementatations.

Comment: @Sajeetharan In that case, any changes to a property in `_stores` will also change in `oldSettings` - your `StoreSettings` class is a reference type. Since you're changing them in both collections, `Except` will always return zero - the collections are identical.

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399521/get-differences-between-two-list. You may use FindAll.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan my old collection does not implement inotify propertychanged

Comment: @Sajeetharan From your code, it seems both collections are `ObservableCollections` (implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged`), and both contain items of the *same type*, `StoreSettings`. How can you say the old collection doesn't implementn `INotifyPropertyChanged` if it's the same objects?

Comment: @rightfold Not sure if it is still an issue, but sticking breakpoints on auto-properties is not trivial, unlike regular properties.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan My bad!, i guess thats the problem here. Just now i realised, will check again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these two lists contain the same object instances, then it won't work because changes to object properties in one list will be applied to the other list also (since they are the same instances).

This means that you have to either:

1. clone objects before changing them, or
2. create a new instance on each change.

If they are not the same instances (i.e. if they are cloned or came through a database roundrip), then you need to provide a way for the runtime to compare individual properties.

You can either override the `Equals` method of the `StoreSettings`, or use a custom equality comparer for your `StoreSettings` class.

Something like:

```
public class StoreSettingsEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<StoreSettings>
{
    public bool Equals(StoreSettings x, StoreSettings y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, null))
            return object.ReferenceEquals(y, null);

        return
            x.AutoAOD == y.AutoAOD &&
            x.AutoGRN == y.AutoGRN &&  
            ...
    }

    public int GetHashCode(StoreSettings obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var h = 31;
            h = h * 7 + obj.AutoAOD.GetHashCode();
            ...
            return h;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use an [overload of `Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb336390(v=vs.100).aspx) which accepts a custom comparer:

```
var comparer = new StoreSettingsEqualityComparer();
var results = first.Except(second, comparer).ToList();
```

Comment: @goro this does not work, when i debug and check the value for x and y seems to be different always

Comment: @Sajeetharan: can you explain a bit better? Which values are you comparing?

Comment: actually there is a difference in oldsettings and newsettings but it returns results as 0, when i debug the x and y values passed are different.

Comment: @Sajeetharan: I'll update my answer with a test so that you can compare with your code.

Comment: @Sajeetharan: [here is a working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vC66d3) which uses the comparer from my answer, try to see what differs from your tests.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you the changes

```
               List<StoreSettings> changes = _vmStoreconfig.oldSettings.FindAll(delegate(StoreSettings item1) 
                    {
                                StoreSettings found = _vmStoreconfig.Stores.Find(delegate(StoreSettings item2) {
                                // Specify comparisons between properties here
                                return item2.propertyA == item1.propertyA ...;
                    }
                    return found != null;
                });
```